# Carousel indicators in Bootstrap carousel not working in Sharepoint

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sharepoint, carousel

I'm feeding a Bootstrap carousel into a Sharepoint Content Query webpart. It's working well as the webpart is bringing in data from a custom list in SharePoint (thanks to this [post](http://www.avtex.com/2016/04/creating-a-bootstrap-carousel-in-sharepoint/)) however the carousel indicators aren't working. Note that the next and previous buttons on each side of the banner are working.

Can anyone see anything wrong with this section of code?

```
<div id="bootstrap-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

<ol class="carousel-indicators">
 <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
 <xsl:variable name="position">
 <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
 </xsl:variable>
 <xsl:choose>
 <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
 <li class="active" data-target="#bootstrap-carousel" data-slide-to="{$position}"></li>
 </xsl:when>
 <xsl:otherwise>
 <li data-target="#bootstrap-carousel" data-slide-to="{$position}"></li>
 </xsl:otherwise>
 </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:for-each>
 </ol>
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
  <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
  <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.CallItemTemplate"/>
 </xsl:for-each>
 </div>



 <a class="left carousel-control" href="#bootstrap-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev"><span class="fa fa-chevron-left"> </span></a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#bootstrap-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next"><span class="fa fa-chevron-right"> </span></a>


 </div>
```